# Fetch name of ActiveRecord::Relation object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Afternoon all,

I have a Month model which has many hotels. A hotel belongs_to a month and has a name, info, picture, twitter_id etc and a winner column, which is a boolean. In my index view for months, for each month i would like to show the name of the hotel where "winner" is true.

I have been trying the following where queries;

```
<% @months.each do |month| %>
    <td><%= month.date %></td>
    <td><%= month.created_at.strftime("%v") %></td>
    <td><%= month.hotels.where(winner: "true") %></td>
<% end %>
```

and this returns; `#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fae1ed9cd70>` 
(slapping .name on the end just gives the relation name of "hotel")

How could I perform a query that retrieves the winning hotel's name?

Any pointers would be great thanks, my code is as follows;

months_controller.rb

```
def show
    @month = Month.find(params[:id])
    @hotels = @month.hotels
  end

  def index
    @months = Month.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).includes(:hotels)
  end
```

If you need more code just shout. cheers Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `where` query, it returns to you an array of the hotels object. Maybe you should try to use a `find_by` alternative to retrieve only one hotel like this:

```
month.hotels.find_by_winner(true).name
```

EDIT:

```
<% winner = month.hotels.find_by_winner(true) %>
<%= winner.name if winner %>
```

This way the name method would be called only if winner is not nil.

Comment: Hi Murifoz, by removing .name this correctly retrieves the winning hotel. One of my months doesn't have a winner and is correctly showing nothing. however, when calling .name it errors out with undefined method name for Nilclass. This name thing is puzzling?

Comment: Well, if the month doesn't have a winner, it would return nil, and if you call the .name method on nil, it would give you this error. What you can do is perform a nil checker. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Absolute legend, that hadn't occurred to me! thanks murifox! Andy

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is one winner in each month:

```
month.hotels.where(winner: "true").first.try(:name)
```

If there may be many winners you can do:

```
month.hotels.where(winner: "true").pluck(:name)
```

This will return an array of all winners names.

Comment: Hi Erez, this only seems to retrieve the name of the first hotel under the corresponding month. One of my months doesn't have a winner yet, so it shouldn't show anything, but is returning "Ritz"